# Possible to write an Apache file handler in Php?

Tags: php, apache

I wonder if and how it is possible to write a custom "file handler" (parsing a file and rendering it with bonuses) for Apache 2 in PHP?  Files are text files, and they could be large, so I'm not thinking of loading them entirely in memory, but processing them line by line.

I'm comfortable with Java and other languages but still rookie in PHP; I chose PHP because it's light and especially deployable on every Apache-capable machine (even small NAS), and, well, I like PHP.

Thank you for your hints.

Comment: Interesting question!  Worst case scenario, you should be able to STDIO to a PHP.exe running your code, and your PHP code can open these streams and deal with CGI.

Comment: Actual Apache handlers and filters cannot be written in PHP. You can utilize a PHP script for preprocessing other files by redirecting file requests via RewriteRules onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to write a file handler in php.

However you could use the rewrite engine to redirect those files that you want to handle to a php script that, then, does the job.

the original file can be obtained from the server variables.